# How does this fraction $\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{a}$ become $y = a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was learning SET. To solve a problem for **Y** at some point I stopped right here  **$\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{a}$**, and I couldn't go further. Then I opened the solution book and there I found that everything I did was right up-to this $\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{a}$ line. And I also found that, the solution book solved the problem just adding this line $y = a$ after my line ($\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{a}$), but there is no any explicit explanation. Can anybody expert in mathematics please tell me how this fraction ($\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{a}$) has been converted to **$y = a$**? Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Just multiply both sides by $ay$. Or for the equation $y=a$, simply divide instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s plenty of ways. You can take reciprocals on both sides, since $r=s$ implies $\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{s}$ when they are not zero. So you get
$$\frac{1}{\quad\frac{1}{y}\quad} = \frac{1}{\quad\frac{1}{a}\quad}$$
and this is the same as $y=a$.

Or you can multiply through by $ay$ and then cancel. You get
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{y} &= \frac{1}{a}\\
\frac{ay}{y} &= \frac{ay}{a}\\
\frac{a}{1} &= \frac{y}{1}\\
a &= y
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks Arturo Magidin for your helping hand. I have used the multiplication method. Because I couldn't understand the reciprocal method yet. I knew that 1/y would be y/1 and if I cancel out then both side will have only **1 = 1**. On that case I wouldn't be able to solve the problem for **Y**.

Comment: @Coduser: Sorry, but what you say is nonsensical. “would be $y/1$” doesn’t make any sense, and there is *nothing* you can cancel to get $1=1$. So whatever you think you would be doing, you are doing something incorrect.

Comment: Magadin You are right. I made the mistake. I think I should understand the reciprocal concept properly. I just could not understand how you have got **1 over 1/y** on both sides. That's why I became more confused dude.

Comment: @Coduser: You don't get 1 over $\frac{1}{y}$ on both sides. You get that on one side, and you get 1 over $\frac{1}{a}$ on the other. What you need to remember is that $\frac{1}{\quad\frac{1}{y}\quad} = \frac{\quad\frac{1}{1}\quad}{\frac{1}{y}}$, and how to divide fractions.